# How to get specific part of URI?

Tags: php, wrapper

The title is a bit misleading. Let me explain better with an example:

Suppose that I've an URI like this: `localhost/api/user/method/5`. 
the URI is composed by:

**`[0]`** => **localhost:** *server base path*
**`[1]`** => **api:** *application base path*
**`[2]`** => **user:** *represents the user controller*
**`[3]`** => **getUser:** *represents the method `getUser`*
**`[4]`** => **5:** *is a parameter*

what I want to do is create an instance of the class `User` available in the `user.php` file controller, call the function `getUser` available in the `user` controller and pass the parameter `5`. So should be something like (example code):

```
$Class = ucfirst("user"); 
// create an instance
$ctr = new $Class();
// and call the requested function
$ctr->$func();  //$func should be valorized with getUser in this case
```

now I've created a class that's a simple `router` system.

```
<?php

    class Route
    {
        /**
         * @var array $_listUri List of URI's to match against
         */
        private $_listUri = array();

        /**
        * @var array $_listCall List of closures to call 
        */
       private $_listCall = array();

       /**
       * @var string $_trim Class-wide items to clean
       */
       private $_trim = '/\^$';

       /**
       * add - Adds a URI and Function to the two lists
       *
       * @param string $uri A path such as about/system
       * @param object $function An anonymous function
       */
       public function add($uri, $function)
       {
          $uri = trim($uri, $this->_trim);
          $this->_listUri[] = $uri;
          $this->_listCall[] = $function;
       }

       // submit - Looks for a match for the URI and runs the related function

       public function submit()
       {    
           $uri = isset($_REQUEST['uri']) ? $_REQUEST['uri'] : '/';
           $uri = trim($uri, $this->_trim);

          $replacementValues = array();

          //  List through the stored URI's

         foreach ($this->_listUri as $listKey => $listUri)
         {
             // See if there is a match

              if (preg_match("#^$listUri$#", $uri))
              {
                 //Replace the values

                 $realUri = explode('/', $uri);
                 $fakeUri = explode('/', $listUri);

                // Gather the .+ values with the real values in the URI

                foreach ($fakeUri as $key => $value) 
                {
                    if ($value == '.+') 
                    {
                        $replacementValues[] = $realUri[$key];
                    }
                }

               // Pass an array for arguments

               call_user_func_array($this->_listCall[$listKey], $replacementValues);
        }   
      } 
   }
}
```

what I want to achieve is take  the base url path as `[2] => user` and save it as controller, the `[3] index` should be used as a function to be indicated on the controller, and the `[4] index` should be the parameter, note that: the `[4] index` could be an optional parameter. Actually the class simple working as follow:

```
$route->add('/user/.+', function($name) {
    echo "Name $name";
});

$route->submit();
```

so if the user insert this URI in the browser:

```
localhost/api/user/5
```

will be printed:

> Name 5

How I can implement the logic explained above?

**UPDATE - Call function with some parameters**

```
$controller = $realUri[0]; 'Contains the controller to load
$func = $this->_listCall[$listKey]; 'contains the function to load

include dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . "/application/controllers/" .
$controller . ".php" ;

$Class = ucfirst($controller);

$ctr = new $Class();
//$ctr->$func($replacementValues);
```

the variable `$replacementValues` is like this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "9" }
```

and contains all the parameter passed in the url:

```
localhost/api/user/method/5/9
```

so how can I pass all this parameter to the function `$func()`?

Comment: Check out [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url)

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ could you provide a little example?

Comment: https://eval.in/519029 and [rtfm](http://php.net/parse_url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url        = "http://localhost:80/api/user/method/5";
$parsedUrl  = parse_url($url);
var_dump($parsedUrl);
```

**Will print**

```
array(4) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["path"]=>
  string(18) "/api/user/method/5"
}
```

Now it's pretty simple to decompose your path as you want :

```
if (!empty($parsedUrl['path'])) {
    $patg = explode('/',$parsedUrl['path']); 
}
```

Comment: Okay I've implemented succesfully this change and working pretty well. Ony that there is a bit problem. If the URI is like this: `localhost/api/user/method/5/9` means that I want call the `method` function available in `user` controller, and also there is `5` and `9` they are parameters. If you can see my class above, I save this parameter in the `$replacementValues` variable. So how can I pass this parameter  to the function of the controller? 'Cause the main problem is that they are an array of values. Any ideas? list of param:: `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "9"
}`

Comment: @Gordon your score is amazing !! any advices ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis yes. don't be impressed by high reputation scores. It only means I spent too much time on this site ;)

Comment: @Gordon `call_user_func_array()` working only for the passed function, I've updated the question for add some details.

Comment: @Dillinger I dont see the problem?

Comment: @Gordon, well in each function should I split the array and get the index, there is another way for do this?

Comment: @Dillinger what do you mean split in each function? you just call `call_user_func_array([$controllerInstance, $method], $arguments)` - can you clarify?

Comment: @Gordon, you're right, seems working but there is a bit problem: if `$replacementValues` contains `array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "9" }` when I do: `call_user_func_array([$ctr, $func], $replacementValues);` and execute so a `var_dump($replacementVaules);` in the called function I get only `string(1) "5"`, the value `9` missing. Why?

Comment: @Dillinger then you are doing something wrong. `call_user_func_array(function() { var_dump(func_get_args()); }, [5, 9]);` will give 5 and 9 in the output

Comment: @Dillinger `call_user_func_array` will pass each element in the array as individual parameter. Maybe that's your problem. The signature for your $func would be `fn($a, $b)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103523/discussion-between-dillinger-and-gordon).